# Get default value defined in preferences.xml

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, getter

I want to retrieve the default value from the myPreferences.xml with the AndroidPreferenceManager. I got it to work with int and strings, but how to load the default value from a Boolean?

Snippet from helperMethods:

```
    public static void putPref(String key, String value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
    public static Boolean getPrefBoolean(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, null);
    }
```

Snippet from myPreferences:

```
        <EditTextPreference
        app:defaultValue="@string/value_content_id"
        app:key="@string/key_device_id"
        app:summary="@string/device_id"
        app:title="@string/title_content_id" />


        <Preference
        app:key="key_wifi"
        app:summary="WifiSettings"
        app:title="Set Wifi"  />

        <CheckBoxPreference
        app:defaultValue="true"
        app:key="@string/key_app_lock"
        app:summary="@string/summary_app_lock"
        app:title="@string/title_app_lock" />
```

the goal is to get the default value from the myPreference.xml when no value has been set yet. It works with Strings, and Integers but how with an boolean? Is there a workaround?Sometimes the default might be a string, int or boolean. My problem right now is, that SharedPreferences.getBoolean doesnt accept a null value as parameter. What I really don't want to do is defining the default value when using get. Since it's already declared in the preference.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain what you are asking. But if you check for the presence of the preference using the contains method on the SharedPreferences, you can determine if you would like to return null instead inside of your helper method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String)